# Pyinstaller and PyQt5

Tags: pyqt5

The crux of the problem: using `pyinstaller`, I compile the application to `PyQt5`. A PyQt5 directory with libraries is created in the dist `/myGui` directory, for example `QtGui.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu`.so. But Linux operating system has this library in `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt5`. How do I force the binary to use the library from `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt5`?

I've tried specifying `sys.path.insert(0, '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages')` and `sys.path.insert(0, '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt5')` before importing "from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets", but it gave no results, the application throws an error.

Translated into English via google so sorry in advance.

Comment: The whole concept of pyinstaller is to provide a full working environment even in systems where the required libraries are not installed. Why do you want to "force" a hardcoded path? Consider that, while that path seems standard, there's no guarantee that it would be the same on other computers. For instance, on one of my machines it's `/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/PyQt5`.

Comment: The program will be used only on the version of the Linux distribution for which it is created. It is very simple, but it takes 26 MB

Comment: Pyinstaller works by using *its own* files, not those already installed in the computer. Nowadays, a 26mb file is not considered a problem, if you're worried about that, just use a repository and/or a package with all required files for your program.

Answer (score 0):

option that works for me (перевожу через google.translate, поэтому извините)

`cython main.py --embed`

`gcc -Os -I /usr/include/python3.7m -o main main.c -lpython3.7m -lpthread -lm -lutil -ldl`
(instead of python3.7m you should use your version of python)
Will not work if there is a hyphen in the file name main.py (for example main-main.py don`t work)